# Changing variable from DataTable in Dialog

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, javabeans

I have a question about updating variable inside dataTable component, which was sended to dialog component.

I want to have dialog box with options. There are informations about user (user data editing).
`ManageUsers` class have `UserDAO selectedUser` property, `UserDAO` class contains User POJO (login, email etc).
`ManageUsers.updateUser` persists data in database.

How can I update selectedUser through inputText?
I can not use `p:inplace` component because I have a problem with `h:forms` and `facelets` (changing to production stage does not resolve this problem).

Glassfish: 3.1
Primefaces: 2.2
JSF: 2.1 (now MyFaces 2.1.3)

```
<h:form prependId="false"> 

   <p:growl id="growl"/>

   <!--            Data table with all users-->
   <p:dataTable id="userTable" var="u" value="#{manageUsers.users}"> 

      <p:column headerText="login" style="width:150px" filterBy="#{u.user.login}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
         <h:outputText value="#{u.user.login}" />
      </p:column> 

      <p:column headerText="email" style="width:150px" filterBy="#{u.user.email}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
         <h:outputText value="#{u.user.email}" /> 
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="apikey" style="width:150px" filterBy="#{u.user.apikey}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"> 
         <h:outputText value="#{u.user.apikey}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Options" > 
         <p:commandButton update="display" oncomplete="userDialog.show()" 
                      image="ui-icon ui-icon-search"> 
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{u}" target="#{manageUsers.selectedUser}" /> 
         </p:commandButton> 
      </p:column> 

   </p:dataTable>   

   <!--            Dialog box with options-->
   <p:dialog appendToBody="true" header="User Detail" widgetVar="userDialog" resizable="false" 
           width="500" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" onCloseUpdate="growl,userTable"> 
      <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4"> 

         <h:outputText value="Login" />
         <p:inputText  required="true" value="#{manageUsers.selectedUser.user.login}" />

         <h:outputText value="Email" />
         <p:inputText  required="true" value="#{manageUsers.selectedUser.user.email}" />

         <p:commandButton value="save and exit" action="#{manageUsers.updateUser}" update="growl,userTable" onclick="userDialog.hide()" />

      </h:panelGrid> 
   </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

[image: Example view]

Comment: does your update action update the backing bean's information in the list (#{manageUsers.updateUser}). If the referenced data isn't updated then this wouldn't be reflected: your code looks like this wouldn't be the case since the reference is explicit but double check in the debugger.

Comment: PROBLEM RESOLVED. Setters was not fired. I don't know why, but when I remove appendToBody="true", then setters work perfectly. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PROBLEM RESOLVED. Setters was not fired. I don't know why, but when I remove appendToBody="true", then setters work perfectly. Anyone know why?
```

The setters weren't fired because setting **appendToBody** to **true** might cause the **dialog** to be out the **form** component.From the Primefaces User Guide (3.0.M4):

```
    Use appendToBody with care as the page definition and html dom would be different, for
example if dialog is inside an h:form component and appendToBody is enabled, on the browser
dialog would be outside of form and may cause unexpected results. In this case, nest a form inside
a dialog.
```